# Showing there is no retraction $r: B^2 \to S^1$.

Tags: general-topology

For topological spaces $X \subset Y$ and a continuous retraction $r: Y \to X$, such that $\forall x \in X, r(x) = x$. How would you show, using the functoriality of the fundamental group, that there is no retraction of the unit disc $B^2$ to its boundary $S^1$?

Comment: you mean a retraction from $Y$ to $X$.

Comment: *Future reference*: This is a homework exercise, so you need to first portray your effort to solve it, with more questions than the statement of the original homework question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $r$ is a continuous retraction $B^2 \to S^1$ and let $\iota : S^1 \hookrightarrow B^2$ be the inclusion map. Notice that $r \circ \iota = 1_{S_1} : S^1 \to S^1$, and by functoriality of $\pi_1$ we have induced maps on fundamental groups:
$$1_{\pi_1(S_1)} = (1_{S_1})_* = (r \circ \iota)_* = r_* \circ \iota_* : \pi_1(S^1) \xrightarrow{\iota_*} \pi_1(B^2) \xrightarrow{r_*} \pi_1(S^1)$$
Why is this impossible?

**Hint:** Hover mouse over the grey box below when you've thought about this for a bit longer.

> Can the identity map on a nontrivial group factor through a trivial group?