# show no continuous function exists from unit disk to unit circle such that $r(z)=z$ for every $z \in S^1$

Tags: general-topology

I need to show there does not exist a continuous function

$$f: \mathbb{D}^1 \rightarrow S^1$$

such that $f(z)=z$ for every $z \in S^1$. Do I suppose there exists such an $f$ then find an open subset of $S^1$ whose preimage isn't open in the unit disk? Can I argue $\mathbb{D}^1$ is simply connected while $S^1$ is not ?

Comment: This is not an easy topic depending on what you know. For example do you know that a continuous map from the unit disk to the unit disk has a fix point?

Comment: could I use that the unit disk is simply connected but $S^1$ isn't @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/454774 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/278579.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's define some concepts:
Let $X$ be a topological space, $A\subset X$ not empty. We say that $A$ is a retraction of $X$ is there exists some continuous function $f:X\to A$ such as $f|_{A}=1_{A}$.
If $X$ is simply connected and $A$ is a retract of $X$, then $A$ is simply connected.

Our function $f:\mathbb{D}^1\to\mathbb{S}^1$, case it exists, verifies that $f(z)=z\;,\forall z\in\mathbb{S}^1$. That it, $\mathbb{S}^1$ is a retraction of $\mathbb{D}^1$. Since the unit disk is simply connected(is convex so its contractible) it implies that $\mathbb{S}^1$ is simply connected, but $\pi_{1}(\mathbb{S}^1)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, which is not the trivial group. Hence $\mathbb{S}^1$ is not simply connected, and such function cannot exist.